# How to make =Index Function ignore Zero values?

Tags: excel

My Index formula results in #N/A because the defined dynamic range (Uses Offset) contains a few 0s, is it possible to make Index function ignore 0 values?

Comment: can you post the formula you are using

Comment: The formula is too complicated and long, but the main cause of #N/A is simply because defined deposit range has 0 as one of its values. I've tried to use OFFSET and remove last cell with 0 in dynamic range, but when you are referring to a dynamic range in the formula, it sees the entire column.

Answer (score 0):

The Index function doesn't return #N/A just because the range it is looking at contains zeroes. The fact that it is a dynamic range is irrelevant. Index should only return #N/A if one of it's inputs evaluates to #N/A, or the indexed value found equals #N/A.

You should use the Evaluate Formula tool from the Formulas tab to evaluate where the #N/A value is being introduced.